# PyQGIS path error when in loop

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-processing

I have a very simple script which takes in table of X,Y --> Convert to point --> Convert to Shape

```
centerpoint = r'C:/Users/YYY/pointfile.xlsx|layername=Sheet1'
pointshape = r'C:/Users/YYY/pointshape.shp'


processing.run("native:createpointslayerfromtable", {'INPUT':centerpoint,
                                                    'XFIELD':'POINT_X','YFIELD':'POINT_Y','ZFIELD':'','MFIELD':'',
                                                    'TARGET_CRS': QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem('ESRI:102080'),
                                                    'OUTPUT':pointshape})


processing.run("native:rectanglesovalsdiamonds", {'INPUT':pointshape,
                                                  'SHAPE':0,'WIDTH':Width_of_Bld,'HEIGHT':Height_of_Bld,'ROTATION':Rotation_of_Bld,'SEGMENTS':2,
                                                  'OUTPUT': bldshape})
```

This script is in a simple for loop over a list. It works fine when it's processing the first item in the list, but when it reaches the second item, I get error:

```
Application path not initialized
ERROR 1: C:/Users/YYY/pointshape.shp is not a directory.
```

Which is weird because it's obvious that is name of file to be generated and not a directory. I don't need `pointshape` so I was hoping it would just simply overwrite it.

Comment: How do you use the code above in the loop? Could you add the loop part?